# Maven - dynamically creating a map, and referring to it

Tags: maven

Our generic Maven build needs to pass on a number of properties to child processes.

Right now, we are providing these as environment variables, and reading them in individually as properties.

These properties are then substituted into a file to configure a test runtime, and provided to the Failsafe plugin as environment variables for the test run.

The above is fine, except for a couple of things:

1. The environment variable -> property map is manual - we need a property definition for every environment variable we want to pull in.
2. Specifying environment variables to Failsafe is again manual - we need a variable definition for every environment variable we want to pass on.

Right now, if we have 20 environment variables, we have 20 lines for each of these stages, and that's getting tedious quickly.

Is there a better way to do this?

My naive thoughts include (though I can't find a way to achieve it):

1. Define Maven properties dynamically, potentially based on a regex, from environment variables.
2. From Maven properties, automatically construct a list of environment variables, to be passed to Failsafe, again preferably via a regex.

Comment: What about dump environment variables to file outside of Maven and pass the file to surefire as property `systemPropertiesFile`?

Comment: Sadly, a system property isn't an environment variable.  I need to pass environment variables.  And I'm not sure how I can dump a group of unenumerated environment variables to a file from Maven - I suspect it's the same problem again.